# How to add id or class to an item eg: image in slider revolution for adding css to it?

Tags: css, wordpress, class

I'm trying to add some CSS to an image in slider revolution but I couldn't as I don't know how to target that image in the revolution slider to apply CSS on it...

is there a way to do it?
[trying to add CSS to image in rev slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yTwG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Select the "Image Layer" that you'd like to apply custom CSS. Then, navigate to "Layer Options" and select "Custom CSS" as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the CSS for all the images then you can use like this;

```
 img{
    /*Your css goes here*/
    }
```

But if you want to use your css for some specific image/images then you should use css class for this purpose. e.g image class.
In HTML

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/" alt="myImage" class="image" />
```

and CSS

```
 .image{
/*your css goes here*/
}
```

You should also enhance your skills about HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the rev slider and select the defaults (Attributes based on your view). Here you can assign an id to the module id. Navigate to the custom css and target the module with the ID you previously set.